# Phrasal verb, slang or a word for gather around or to look at something or someone with joy

Tags: vocabulary, phrasal-verbs, slang, word-play

I'm looking for a slang, phrasal verb or a word that explains people looking at something or someone. E.g. when people gather around a new-born baby and look at it with joy. Or when someone is looking at the marvelous painting hung at the wall.

Answer (score 1):

[**to admire**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/admire) comes very close:

> to look at (something or someone) with enjoyment

MW gives the following example sentence:

> We gazed out the window and **admired** the scenery

Comment: +1 nice search. Another option could be [*gaze*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/gaze_1?q=gaze) - to look steadily at somebody/something for a long time, either because **you are very interested** or surprised. However, it's a poorer choice to your word. :)

Comment: Admiring or gazing at the new-born, doesn't sound good.

Comment: @ArdisEll - Why do you think that doesn't sound good?  "Admiring the newborn" is perfectly normal, standard English.

Comment: Are there any more words, slangs or phrasal verbs that could be used here?